# Font and Background Color of iText FreeText annotation

Tags: fonts, background, annotations, itext, freetext

This is how i create a free text annotation in iText

```
PdfAnnotation stamp = PdfAnnotation.createFreeText(stamper.getWriter(), rectangleObject, "text String", pdfAppearance);
```

I cannot set a transparent background for free text. i used PdfName.IC like this

```
stamp.put(PdfName.IC, new PdfArray(new float[]{r, g, b}));
```

Also regarding font, how can the size and font in iText be equal to the html font and size.

This is how I did it

```
BaseFont.createFont("helvetica", BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED), 12);
```

my font in javascript is helvetica 12pt

Comment: Usually we recommend only one "question" per post here. Regardless, to your second question, `BaseFont` is essentially the font file itself and `Font` is version of that font at a specific size (among other attributes). To create a 12pt Helvetica font you'd use `Font font = new Font(BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED), 12);`

Comment: Thank you chris. To answer my other question, i noticed that in Acrobat when creating a FreeTextTypeWriter annotation, there is no way to even set a background color. Hence, when setting one using iText, transparent background color is not possible.